# What available ways are there to write libraries that can be used in rails? How they works? How to "install" them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Sorry for the title but I can't find words to explain this exactly.
I'm a bit confused in rails when I have to choose where should I place my external libraries.

For example, if I want to prepare a gem which will contain a lot of helpers that I can share across all my applications, what should it do? Should it install those helpers under my app/helpers dir?

Actually these are all directories I know where I could place external libraries:

- vendor/assets
- app/helpers
- vendor/plugins [**which has been deprecated if I'm not wrong**]
- lib/assets
- lib/tasks

What if I want create a method that can be used in controllers if they include something, where should I place such a file?

If I create a gem that can be used in rails, where should it install files?

I'm a bit lost, I always create a file but I feel a bit uncomfortable because I always don't know where should I place it.

**Edit 1:**

I want to add also a special case, where do you place a library written in javascript which directory structure is hardly tied up toghether, so you can't move css/images into different directories. How do you handle this? I created a directory in vendor/assets to make it works, but I don't know if it's the best way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually reading around and getting information on IRC chat, I understood these things:

- vendor/assets Should be used for libraries that are "completely" external to Rails, for example something that interact with a C++ library or things like that.
- app/helpers is for helpers useful only for this application
- vendor/plugins has been deprecated
- lib/assets is for libraries that you would like to use (such as javascript libraries), that you don't want store in a gem (or aren't released as gems).

This is definitely not a complete answer, but actually is the only one I've found.

About gems and how they should be build, I'll make a new question.